# Which components must be included in the HDR plasmid?

Tags: gene, genetics, computational-biochemistry, design, crispr

I am trying to design a plasmid for our knock in experiment and wanted to clarify some technical issues.

I wanted to know exactly which components must be included in the plasmid.

I know that I have to include the 5' homology arm , insertion gene sequence, marker sequence and 3' homology arm.
But, I would like to know for certain the following details:

1. Should I take the whole sequence of the gene or do I need to remove the introns/UTR regions or any other unnecessary part of the sequence?
2. Which sequence should I choose for gene insertion , gene sequence or mRNA transcript sequence?
3. When designing plasmids, should I insert extra promoters and/or terminators with the insertion genes?

Additionally, can you recommend an online tool to design HDR Plasmid?
I have already tried using Alt R HDR design tool and Benchling but our target genome is not available there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You would probably get better answers on the [Biology forum](https://biology.stackexchange.com/). It would also help to mention whether you are using a commercial backbone for the plasmid or designing the whole construct from scratch.

Comment: Thank you @Cloudberry for your suggesion.